# Finding a signal output $y(n)$ with input signal $x(n)$ and impulse response $h(n)$ with a DTFT

Tags: signal-processing, signal, linear-systems

I am studying for my Digital Signal Processing course and I am stucking on the following exercise:

> Given an $\text{LTI}$-system with input signal $$x(n)=\frac{1}{4^n}u(n)$$
> and impulse response $$h(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}u(n),$$
> calculate the output $y(n)$ of the system using a DTFT.

So, even though this isn't cleared up in the exercise, I imagine $u(n)$ is the discrete-time step function, so it is defined as $$u(n) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & n\geq 0 \\
      0 & n < 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$
Well, shouldn't the answer be the convolution $(x*h)(n)$? I have tried to use the convolution theorem but I am unable to calcualte the inverse DTFT for the product of those two DTFT's. What should I do now? I am very much confused and do not know how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_time_fourier_transform) gives the mathematical expression for DTFT of signals of the format $a^n u[n]$. More importantly, It also mentions the [Convolution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Convolution) which allows for the computation of convolution via the DTFT.

Answer (score 1):

As seen here at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Table_of_discrete-time_Fourier_transforms), the DTFT of signals of the form $a^n u[n]$ is

$$
a^n u[n] \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1 - a e^{-i \omega}}
$$

To perform convolution of two sequences, it is enough to use to the convolution theorem (also mentioned in the above [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Convolution) article)

$$
x * y = \rm{DTFT}^{-1} \left[\rm {DTFT} \{x\}\cdot \rm {DTFT}\{y\}\right]
$$

Comment: One question: How would I go about computing the Inverse DTFT?

Comment: The same Wikipedia article gives the formula for the inverse transform (It is the same procedure as finding the Fourier series.). Else, you can use the table of transforms to find the inverse if the expression you want to invert can be brought to the same format as any of the entries in that table.

Comment: It is, but the multiplication makes the integral too complicated to compute.

Comment: Can you post the result in the question using the edit option below the question ? A method used frequently is [Partial fraction expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Partial_fraction_expansion). One you expand using partial fraction, the individual terms are simple and can be inverted using the table of transforms and you need to utilise the linearity property to combine the individual inverses.

Comment: The integral is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\frac{e^{i\omega n}}{(1-\frac{1}{4}e^{-i\omega})(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega})}d\omega}$. Perhaps if $z=e^{i\omega}$ and you try to break it into partial sums, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @AJN, did anything work for you?

Comment: You don't have to do the integral if you do partial fraction expansion $\frac{A}{1 - e^{-i\omega}/4} + \frac{B}{1 - e^{-i\omega}/2}$. Once you expand, you can use the table to invert the individual terms  (due to linearity property).